# LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1

Tags: authentication, ldap

> LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1

I know "52e" code is when username is valid, but password is invalid. I am using the same user  name and password in my apache studio, I was able to establish the connection succesfully to LDAP.

**Here is my java code**

```
    String userName = "*******";
    String password = "********";
    String base ="DC=PSLTESTDOMAIN,DC=LOCAL";
    String dn = "cn=" + userName + "," + base;  
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://******");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    LDAPAuthenticationService ldap = new LDAPAuthenticationService();
   // LdapContext ctx;
    DirContext ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

**My error is on this line**: `ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);`

I do not know what exactly is causing this error.

Answer (score 43):

data 52e - [Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors)

You probably need something like

```
String dn = "cn=" + userName + "," + "CN=Users," + base;
```

Comment: You should check out a better way to find users: https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/dba1d74d172f9a3f13fc375f6d17370b6da91adf/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/BasicAdminSearchBind.java?at=master

Answer (score 38):

For me the issue resolved when I set the principal section like this:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userId@domainWithoutProtocolAndPortNo);
```

You set this in the environment HashTable that you pass while instantiating `javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext` i.e., `context = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);` where env is a HashTable.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Can you please provide us with more explanation on why does it work?

Answer (score 19):

In my case I have to use something like `<username>@<domain>` to successfully login.

`sample_user@sample_domain`

Answer (score 18):

`52e    1326    ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE`    Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.  Will prevent most other errors from being displayed as noted.

https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors

Answer (score 14):

When you use Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION as "simple", you need to supply the userPrincipalName attribute value (user@domain_base).

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar  issue when using AD on CAS , i.e. 52e error, In my case application accepts the Full Name when in the form of CN= instead of the actual username.

For example, if you had a user who's full name is Ross Butler and their login username is rbutler --you would normally put something like, cn=rbutler,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com but ours failed everytime.  By changing this to cn=Ross Butler,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com it passed!!

Comment: One way to visualize the syntax AD expects, is to use the 'Attribute Editor' tab, as explained in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/399000/active-directory-viewing-attribute-editor-after-finding-an-account-via-aducs). If you scroll down to 'cn', you may find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue is resolved by adding domain name in user name as follow:

```
string userName="yourUserName";
string password="passowrd";
string hostName="LdapServerHostName";
string domain="yourDomain";
System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes option = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer; 
string userNameWithDomain = string.Format("{0}@{1}",userName , domain);
DirectoryEntry directoryOU = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + hostName, userNameWithDomain, password, option);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you debug and loook at ctx=null,maybe your username hava proble ,you shoud write like
"ac\administrator"(double "\") or "administrator@ac"

Answer (score 2):

For me issue is resolved by changing envs like this:

```
 env.put("LDAP_BASEDN", base)
 env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"user@domain")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your solution a bit and edit your question accordingly. For more hints, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

For me the cause of the issue was that the format of username was incorrect. It was earlierly specified as "mydomain\user". I removed the domain part and the error was gone.

PS I was using ServerBind authentication.

Comment: you are really right. I removed domain name. it worked for me thx great

Answer (score 2):

I've tested three diferent approaches and them all worked:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user@domain.com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=user,OU=one,OU=two,DC=domain,DC=com");
```

If you use the last one, don't forget to set all the OU's where the user belongs to. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP is trying to authenticate with AD when sending a transaction to another server DB. This authentication fails because the user has recently changed her password, although this transaction was generated using the previous credentials. This authentication will keep failing until ... unless you change the transaction status to Complete or Cancel in which case LDAP will stop sending these transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Using domain Name may solve the problem (get domain name using powershell: **$env:userdomain**):

```
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    String principalName = "domainName\\userName";
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://URL:389/OU=ou-xx,DC=fr,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Your Password");

    try {
        DirContext authContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
        // user is authenticated
        System.out.println("USER IS AUTHETICATED");
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        // Authentication failed
        System.out.println("AUTH FAILED : " + ex);

    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Care to explain why using domain is the solution ?

Comment: I think some LDAP expects domain. If we pass only username, the server won't accept.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I misconfigured email credentials then I corrected

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    WindowsStrategy = require('passport-windowsauth'),
    User = require('mongoose').model('User');

module.exports = function () {
    passport.use(new WindowsStrategy({ldap: {
        url:            'ldap://corp.company.com:389/DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com',
        base:           'DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com',
        bindDN:         'myid@corp.company.com',
        bindCredentials:'password',
        tlsOptions: {
            ca: [fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem")],
          },
    }, integrated: false},
    function(profile, done) {
        console.log('Windows');
        console.log(profile);
        User.findOrCreate({
            username: profile.id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Unknown user'
                });
            }

            if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Invalid password'
                });
            }

            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Please remove domain from the username "mydomain\user". please put "user" only. do not put domain and backslash .

You do not use ldaps://examplehost:8080(**do not use s with ldaps coz cert is required**), **use ldap://examplehost:8080** then use **non-TLS port number**. it worked for me.