# ldap authentication failing for some users. SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

my ldap authentication code is failing for certain users in the company. I have a hunch that it might be due to certain special characters in the password. Is this possible. Thanks in advance for anyone who helps.

here is the code :

```
try {
    LdapContextSource ctxSrc= new LdapContextSource();
    ctxSrc.setUrl(url);
    ctxSrc.setBase(base);
    ctxSrc.setUserDn(userDn);
    ctxSrc.setPassword(password);
    ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet();
    LdapTemplate ld= new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);

    AndFilter filters = new AndFilter();
      filters.and(new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", user));
      boolean auth= ld.authenticate(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH, filters.encode(),pwd);

      if(auth==true)
      {
           r="true";
           ret="home";
        Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("user",user);
        //setting cookie to expiry in 30 mins
        loginCookie.setMaxAge(1440*60);
        response.addCookie(loginCookie);
        System.out.println("right");
      }
      else
      {
         r="false";
         ret="false";
      }


}catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("not right");
}
```

the error which comes in the logs :

```
org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1

at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:182) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:285) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:119) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:110) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1494) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1385) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.altair.skillset.EmployeeSearchController.doPost(EmployeeSearchController.java:538) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3135) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:43) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:273) ~[spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps :)

Comment: Depending on how you read the password in (UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1) you might have corrupted special characters.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31411665/18157

Comment: i tried both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. no luck with either of them :(