# Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308:

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap, cuba-platform

I try to use a ldap-server, which is a Microsoft Active Directory. 
    These "`tree`" has following structure:

```
com/ 
name/ 
corp/ 
ger/
Workers/
```

(over 1000 entries) 
and under Workers, there are entries starting with:

```
CN=Mustermann,\Max  
CN=... 
CN=....
```

and so on...

the framework which I use is cuba-studio. 
I had to declare following properties:

```
cuba.web.requirePasswordForNewUsers = false
cuba.web.ldap.enabled = true
cuba.web.ldap.urls = ldap://corpldap.name.com:3268
cuba.web.ldap.base = OU=Workers,DC=ger,DC=corp,DC=name,DC=com
cuba.web.ldap.user = CN=Mustermann Max,OU=Workers,DC=ger,DC=corp,DC=name,DC=com
cuba.web.ldap.password = PASSWORD
cuba.web.standardAuthenticationUsers = admin
cuba.web.ldap.userLoginField = sAMAccountName
```

but, when I try to use this, 
I get following exception:

```
com.haulmont.cuba.security.global.InternalAuthenticationException: Exception is thrown by login provider
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.security.ConnectionImpl.loginInternal(ConnectionImpl.java:225) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.security.ConnectionImpl.login(ConnectionImpl.java:89) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.app.loginwindow.AppLoginWindow.doLogin(AppLoginWindow.java:342) [cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.app.loginwindow.AppLoginWindow.doLogin(AppLoginWindow.java:311) [cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.app.loginwindow.AppLoginWindow.login(AppLoginWindow.java:257) [cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.gui.xml.DeclarativeAction.actionPerform(DeclarativeAction.java:92) [cuba-gui-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.gui.components.WebButton.performAction(WebButton.java:44) [cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.gui.components.WebButton.lambda$new$61446b05$1(WebButton.java:36) [cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1037) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.toolkit.ui.CubaButton.fireClick(CubaButton.java:54) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:119) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:444) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:409) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1435) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:361) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.13.cuba.9.jar:7.7.13.cuba.9]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.sys.CubaApplicationServlet.serviceAppRequest(CubaApplicationServlet.java:300) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.sys.CubaApplicationServlet.service(CubaApplicationServlet.java:191) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.sys.CubaHttpFilter.doFilter(CubaHttpFilter.java:107) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.23]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 ]
            at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:191) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:355) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:139) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:158) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:357) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1441) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1426) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(LdapTemplate.java:1359) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.security.ldap.LdapLoginProvider.authenticateInLdap(LdapLoginProvider.java:131) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.security.ldap.LdapLoginProvider.login(LdapLoginProvider.java:82) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            at com.haulmont.cuba.web.security.ConnectionImpl.loginInternal(ConnectionImpl.java:209) ~[cuba-web-6.8.8.jar:6.8.8]
            ... 65 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 ]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3154) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2886) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2800) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:42) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:343) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
            ... 77 common frames omitted
```

Also I found out, that the exception shall be something with "invalid credentials"

https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/ldap-error-code-49-317195698.html

Also I startet to login with client, using DN= ger\mustermann and it worked.

Does anybody have an idea, how to fix it?

Comment: Prove your settings and credentials are correct. Use ADExplorer and try to bind to this server and submit any queries.

Comment: I could make a connection with Apache Directory Activity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31411665/1531971 Looks like a credential issue. If binding with something like ADExplorer works, then make sure that properties file isn't munging strings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the same user in your CUBA application? 
In [Basic LDAP integration](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.9/ldap_basic.html), LDAP server is used only to store passwords. 
At the same time, access rights of the user should be defined somehow. That is why you have to create the user with the same login in your CUBA application.

Comment: Yes, I tried everything, but dont know, why it does not work..I tried many ways, but still not work

Comment: I create this in application, and with the cuba example, it works, only not with this ldap, but I can make a connection to my ldap. 

Means, something like ger\... and Password, I can make a connection

Comment: Hi,
Try to debug _ConnectionImpl.loginInternal()_. I think it will help to discover the problem.

Comment: Where I can find exactly the ConnectionImpl.loginInternal()? Thx