# LDAP authentication Spring Cloud Data Flow 1.7.0 Snapshot

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-security-ldap

Good day collegues.

I am trying to implement LDAP in my SCDF:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export spring_datasource_url=jdbc:postgresql://xx.xxx.xx.xx:5432/data_flow
export spring_datasource_username=data_flow_main
export spring_datasource_password=secret
export spring_datasource_driver_class_name=org.postgresql.Driver

java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 \
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose \
-jar /mnt/store/viewing-maker/base-operations/scdf/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.task.maximum-concurrent-tasks=300 \
--security.basic.enabled=true \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.enabled=true \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.url="ldap://example.com:389" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.managerDn="CN=123,OU=Служебные пользователи,DC=example,DC=com" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.managerPassword="secret" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.userSearchBase="OU=MyCity" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.userSearchFilter="sAMAccountName={0}" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.groupSearchBase="OU=MyCity" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.groupSearchFilter="member={0}" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.roleMappings.ROLE_MANAGE="ADgroup1" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.roleMappings.ROLE_VIEW="ADGroup2" \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.ldap.roleMappings.ROLE_CREATE="AdGroup3" \
```

But it doesnt work. 
[image: authentication try]

I have the another one project and there is the same configuration. I do authentication via REST and all is working. My LDAP Server returns OK. For clarification, in the correct application, I additionally use:

```
DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator populator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapContext, groupSearchBase);
populator.setSearchSubtree(true);
populator.setRolePrefix(rolePrefix);
populator.setGroupSearchFilter(groupSearchFilter);
```

Comment: Can you please check if your setup is correct? Are you using **Active Directory** as your backend? Looks like the error-code indicates `username is valid but password/credential is invalid` - Please see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411665/ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecurityc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with ANSI instead of utf-8. Some Cyrillic symbols were not recognized by system.