# ldap authentification faild with php ldap_connect with error 49 / 52f

Tags: php, ldap

First of all my credentials are good tested by 100 times.

My PHP Code:

```
$ldapurl = "IP_ADDRESS";
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapurl) or die ("no con"); 
ldap_set_option($ldapconn,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$dn = "user@domain.local";
$ps = 'Password';
$ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn,$dn,$ps);
```

I can bind successfully as anonymous but when I add user and password, bind failed.

LDAP DEBUG:

```
ldap_init: trying c:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf
ldap_init: HOME env is NULL
ldap_init: trying ldaprc
ldap_init: LDAPCONF env is NULL
ldap_init: LDAPRC env is NULL
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://192.168.17.2:389)
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 192.168.17.2:389
ldap_new_socket: 500
ldap_prepare_socket: 500
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.17.2:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 500 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ldap_result ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 14BADDF0 Connections:
* host: 192.168.17.2  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed Mar 20 12:55:22 2019


** ld 14BADDF0 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 14BADDF0 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 14BADDF0 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 14BADDF0 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 14BADDF0 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1 all 1
read1msg: ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1 message type bind
read1msg: ld 14BADDF0 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1
request done: ld 14BADDF0 msgid 1
res_errno: 49, res_error: <80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D3, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52f, v3839>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_result
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_send_unbind
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

Error code is 49 / 52F

```
Account Restrictions are preventing this user from signing in.
```

But I don`t have any restriction on this user. I have already successfully connected myself on AD from the console.

I already try with `$dn = "cn=user,dc=domain,dc=local"` or other combination without success

Comment: You are actually connecting to an AD via an insecure connection? No ldaps or start_tls needed? And the AD actually allows anonymous binds? Have you verified that with your AD-Admins? Because the default AFAIK is to *not* allow anonymous logins...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, I have just used it. It's working for me:

```
$ldap_password = 'password';
$ldap_username = 'email_address';
$ldap_connection = @ldap_connect(IP address);
if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
    echo 'Uh-oh, something is wrong...';
}

// We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
@ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
@ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.
$ad_users = [];
if (@ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){ 
    $ldap_base_dn = 'DC=domain,DC=com';
    $search_filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=*))';
    $attributes = array();
    $attributes[] = 'givenname';
    $attributes[] = 'mail';
    $attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
    $attributes[] = 'sn';
    $result = @ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);   

    if ($result){
        $entries = @ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);

        for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
            if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0]) &&
                 'Shop' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0] &&
                 'Account' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0]){
                $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array('email' => strtolower(trim($entries[$x]['mail'][0])),'first_name' => trim($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]),'last_name' => trim($entries[$x]['sn'][0]));
            }
        }
    }
    ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); // Clean up after ourselves.
}

echo "Retrieved ". count($ad_users) ." Active Directory users\n";
echo '<pre>';print_r($ad_users);echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Same as my code... what is email address? user@dc.dc?

Comment: email should be with the domain as name@domain.com

Comment: In your case, the remote desktop is prevented you.
Please see this link https://serverfault.com/a/718061/512289

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411665/ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecurityc

Comment: Have you seen it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411665/ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecurityc

Comment: You can see all error code meaning here https://ldap.com/ldap-result-code-reference/

Answer (score 0):

52f has always been using a domain user that is in the "protected users" group. Cannot use NTLM to log in, so you must use another method or remove the user from the "protected users" group.