# Rancher Environment variables for LDAP

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, rancher

I am currently working in a project in which we need to get the users from one Active Directory and create the users in another LDAP. For this I am using Springboot project, This works fine when I test in STS. But when I deploy the same project into Rancher (v2.6.13) and configuring the AD details (USERNAME, PASSWORD, BASE URL etc). But when It is trying to establish a connection to LDAP we are getting the below error.

org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839]]

I have tried with below formats of user name

DOMAIN\username
cn=username,ou=service accounts,dc=domain,dc=local
username
cn=username

still no luck. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713897/5510222) I have configured my rancher environment variable with full name, that is CN=username,ou=ounit,dc=domain format. That resolved my error.